# overloading methods in Java

Tags: java, overloading

What conditions must be met so that two methods correctly qualify as overloaded methods?

Is it that two methods must at least differ in their list of arguments such as

```
public void A() { //... }
public void A(int val) { //.. }
```

Hence, a mere change in return-type and/or access modifier wont make two overloaded methods?

Comment: That example shows two different methods. Overloaded methods possess the same name, with different arguments, and the same return type in the same class.

Comment: yes, sure. my carelessness!

Comment: @RyanJ `Overloaded methods possess [..] the same return type [..]` well, I wouldn't bet my money on that part of your statement ...

Comment: Right, my mistake. Return types are not required to be the same.

Comment: one of the best books writen by Deitel (this version it's old) is exactly what you need http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20050909/MotivationGenericMethods.html

Comment: Methods can’t be defined as overloaded methods if they only differ in their return types

Answer (score 5):

You are right. Return types and access modifiers are not qualifying factors for method overloading. What qualifies methods as being overloaded are the parameters that are passed, i.e, either the type of parameters, number of parameters passed or both.

Answer (score 3):

The rules are far from arbitrary: say you had

```
String a() {}
Date a() {}
```

How would you call a? Let's see:

```
Object o = a(); // which a() is called?
```

Methods differring only by access modifier would make even less sense: they would be two copies of the *same* method, but with different behavior.

So the actual rules define the method signature to consist of those parts which are fixed at each call site: name and parameter types. A class may not have two methods with the same signature.

Comment: Method declaration in that manner though produces a compiler error.

Comment: thx. so same name, different method-parameters while the rest i.e. access-modifier, return-type is arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

*you are right brother ,change in access modifier and return type won't make methods **overloaded** . The point is that methods that have same name and different signatures(arguments) are said to be **overloaded** . This is the sufficient condition for making methods **overloaded** .*

Answer (score 0):

Th only rule is that **overloaded methods have to have the same name and different argument types from the JVM perspective**, e.g. you cannot have the following 2 methods:

```
public int methodA(int... array);
public void methodA(int[] array);
```

Does not matter on visibility modifiers or return types.